# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in app/Mage.php on line 670

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, fatal-error, ce-1.9.2.0

I updated from 1.9.1.1 to 1.9.2.

After that first a SQL error showed up, admin panel was still working.
So I decided to do: renew index management and clear cache.

Then it was working again, a few minutes later problem came.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/app/Mage.php on line 670

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Disable the Compiler (uncomment in /your-magento/includes/config.php)
Clear the Cache (Browser+Magento)
Log in and out

Comment: Hi TonkBerlin, thanks for your reply.
I have no longer acces to admin panel :(

on FTP /web/included/config.php is the right file? TKS!
I will post down the text in next message.

Comment: #define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');

Comment: make a # in your second line which begins with "define..."

Comment: Not working:
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(FILE).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src'); #define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(FILE).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');       When: 
 
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(FILE).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src'); #define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(FILE).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');

Comment: What happens when trying to open the /admin ?

Comment: When removing the first # and put the second # back, following shows up: Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Trace:
#0 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/includes/src/__default.php(18052): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/includes/src/__default.php(20837): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#4 {main}

Comment: Both lines needs to begin with a #

Comment: This is a uncommenting function. This disables the compiler by hand.

Comment: When I have at both # the first error return back.

#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');


When I do:
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');

Front controller reached 100 router shows up

Comment: Please make both with #
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');

Now tell error when opening /admin

Comment: When both start with # it gives Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_App' not found in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/app/Mage.php on line 670

Comment: When remove the # at both: Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Trace:
#0 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/includes/src/__default.php(18052): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/includes/src/__default.php(20837): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#4 {main}

Comment: Try deactivating  module in /app/etc/modules - set             <active>true</active>  to <active>false</active>

Comment: mage_compiler.xml or other file?

Comment: Upload all datas from 1.9.2 via FTP

Comment: All modules you dont need at the moment. Plugins and so on...

Comment: OK, thanks so far will look after it later today.

Comment: Solved with > command line update